# FMX get Month and Year from calendar after changed in Dropdown in TCalendar

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Using the TCalendar, it has a option on top of calendar for previous month , next month buttons.  Then it has a dropdown for month and a drop down for year.  I cant seem to find out how to get this data when it changes.

```
Month := Calendar1.???
Year := calendar1.???
```

Also how to know when the previous, next, month dropdown and year dropdown is selected?  `On change`?

To be clear, I can get month and year from selected date. The question is if they change month and year but don't select day.  Then date has not changed so I can't use date to get the current month and year that is in view on the calendar

Comment: either one
procedure TForm1.Calendar1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption:=DateToStr( Calendar1.Day);
end;

procedure TForm1.Calendar1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
// Label1.Caption:=DateToStr( Calendar1.Day);
end;

Comment: @shlomoAbuisak this is for date. If they change month or year but don't select a day. They this would not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, to output the new date to a memo:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(DateToStr(Calendar1.Date));
```

To output to the memo day, month and/or year, add `System.DateUtils` to `uses` and write code like:

```
Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(DayOf( Calendar1.Date)));
Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(MonthOf( Calendar1.Date)));
Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(YearOf( Calendar1.Date)));
```

The `OnChange` event is the one that gets triggered whenever the date of the calendar  is changed.

Comment: This is assuming they change the date or click on a new day. If you just change month. Or year with out selecting a day.  The date has not changed.

Comment: @user41758 I'm not shure I get your point. Whatever you change, day, month, year, alone or in combination, the calendar triggers the `OnChange` event. Or can you give me an example of when it doesn't?

Comment: When you change month or year, the calendar1.date does not change till you select a day.  So if they change date to 2024,  the calendar view will show that year.  But calendar1.date has not changed. I want to know year in the current view.  not based on calendar1.date because it's not updated

Comment: I don't know where you have got the idea that a the Calendar1.Date would not be affected by a change of the year. A `TDate` specifically defines a date consisting of a year, a month and a day, because it is a calculation of days since 30.12.1899. Even if you change only the year, say one year, the value will change with 365 (366 on leap years), for one month it will change by 28, 29, 30 or 31 depending on the month (and possibly leap year), and a change of one day will change the value with 1.

Comment: I showed you with some example code how to extract the various parts of a date value using functions in the System.DateUtils unit. Why dont you try my code and see for your self?

Comment: I just made new program with just this and its working.  still dont work in main project not sure why but confirmed it does work as you state.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I would suggest using `Sysutils.DecodeDate()` instead in this situation. 1 function call instead of 3.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Shure, if that is the wanted output. However, the question listed separately `Month` and `Year`. Thanks anyway for the comment.